# Adding optional argument to macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to add an option "message" attribute to the Clojure time macro.  Basically I want to add an optional custom message to the output of time.  I'm trying to find a bottleneck in my program and having some descriptive messages attached to time's output would be very helpful.

I've tried the following:

```
;optional argument
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [expr & msg]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000.0) " msecs. " (first ~msg)))
     ret#))
```

and

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  ([expr] (time expr ""))
  ([expr msg]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000.0) " msecs. " ~msg))
     ret#)))
```

Both throw exceptions.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws an exception because msg is a list,

say you call it with,

```
(time (+ 1 1) "asd")
```

msg in the macro becomes a function call, ("asd") which fails. Just destructure msg,

```
 [expr & [msg]]
```

and use

```
 ~msg
```

You can also test how macros are expanded with macroexpand,

```
(macroexpand '(time (+ 1 1) "asd"))
```

Also couple of points,

- time is already in core
- your version only accepts and times a single expression.

EDIT: time with optional message,

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [expr & [msg]]
  (let [msg (if (nil? msg) "" msg)]
    `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
       (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000.0) " msecs. " ~msg))
       ret#)))
```

```
(time (+ 1 1))
"Elapsed time: 0.068 msecs. "
2

(time (+ 1 1) "asd")
"Elapsed time: 0.067 msecs. asd"
2
```

Comment: I've been using the core version, however for this case a debug message will be really helpful to me.  Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe some sort of wrapper macro? Doesn't the core version only accept a single expression as well?

Comment: @erikcw Yes you are right my bad core version also accepts a single argument. also added a version with an optional argument